# When are Mercurial bookmarks pushed/pulled implicitly?

Tags: mercurial

Short of explicitly pushing/pulling an individual bookmark, when do bookmarks get copied/updated from repo to repo?

In my testing with two local repos, I couldn't deduce a consistent behavior. Sometimes a push/pull from A to B or B to A would copy/update the bookmarks, sometimes it wouldn't. In some cases, a bookmark gets copied even if the dest repo doesn't already have a bookmark of that name. In other cases, the bookmark is *not* copied even though the dest *does* have a bookmark of that name but pointing to a different changeset. This does not jive with the explanation given at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Bookmarks.

When does the @ renaming enter the picture?

Answer (score 0):

> The explanation given at...

States conditions in short pure English, AFAICS

- When you clone a repository
- When present on both the local and the remote repositories

Comment: Except this is not the actual behavior when I cloned a local repo and pushed/pulled with new/updated bookmarks. The clone works as advertised, but adding bookmark foo to one repo and pushing/pulling to the other sometimes added that new bookmark and sometimes didn't.

Comment: @Jegschemesch: When you exchange data, having updated bookmarks (same name, new revision), "If there is **a divergence** between shared remote and local bookmarks, Mercurial will mark the incoming bookmark either with the path alias, or with a number" New, unique to repo bookmarks not transferred, while you don't do it by hand one time

Comment: That is not the behavior I'm seeing. New, unique to repo bookmarks are sometimes transferred without my explicit say so. Bookmarks shared that diverge are not getting updated nor added as an @ alias.

Comment: Bah, I should have noticed I'm on version 1.9.1 which doesn't have the new @ alias behavior. Maybe the other behavior I'm seeing is also because of the old version.

Comment: OK, I've updated to 2.1.1 now. I'm still seeing the same behavior, but I think I've figured out part of the confusion: a push/pull won't move a bookmark to an ancestor of its current changeset.

Comment: By 'divergent' I think they mean separate branches. I experimented with moving a bookmark onto a separate branch and the pull got me an @ alias bookmark. (Strangely, a push from A to B didn't do anything but a pull from B to A created the alias bookmark.)

Comment: @Jegschemesch Push doesn't propagate new branch on target, pull - does. Divergence (in terms of bookmarks) means *changing in any way* relation changeset-bookmarkname